# what am i missing to get this beforeafter.js plugin to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get [this plug in](http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/) to work, but something isn't right.

My JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/F2Kye/2

This is the `<head>` of my HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.beforeafter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#container').beforeAfter();
    });
</script>
```

This is the body:

```
<div id="container">
    <div><img alt="before" src="center_before.jpg" width="500" height="300" /></div>
    <div><img alt="after" src="center_after.jpg" width="500" height="300" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato i have CSS for the site but nothing that came with the plugin..and i added that and nothing changed..

Comment: The fiddle seems to work fine. I can slide and get the before/after slick effect.

Comment: @Power-Inside weird because it's entirely broken for me in the fiddle

Comment: its broken in safari and chrome for me… would love to figure this out!

Comment: Now it's broken, weird. I swear it worked 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy odd since nothing changed.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yesterday it was not working. Now it's working. weird..weird..

Comment: @thenewseattle damn still not for me..

Comment: The plugin file you linked to delivers a 404 if the HTTP referrer is not http://www.catchmyfame.com, but it works from its own page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're hotlinking the javascript file, but the javascript file URL doesn't work and [results in a 404](http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/beforeafter/js/jquery.beforeafter-1.4.min.js). Either the link is wrong or CatchMyFame.com is set to prevent hotlinking. You need to download the file and host it yourself.

Comment: okay that helps. this is what I'm linking to. is this incorrect?  '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>'

Comment: also can you define which file i need to download?

Comment: Your links to jquery and jqueryUI are both fine.

It's the javascript file for the plugin that has a bad link. You're linking to [this file here](http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/beforeafter/js/jquery.beforeafter-1.4.min.js), but that link doesn't work. Go to the plugin homepage, download the plugin file from there, and upload it to your site.

Answer (score 1):

If you looked at the console in developer tool/firebug, you will notice that browsers are getting 404 for the beforeAfter plugin. It was just a matter of getting the js loaded. I have forked your fiddle to make it work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4fvg3/1/). I am loading the plugin from my server now and it works.
Using
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://binmonk.com/so/jquery.beforeafter-1.4.js"></script>`

Comment: okay! so what do you think the issue was? or what did you change? still not working for me.

Comment: I already mentioned that the 404 issue. Please look at the network responses for your plugin request query.beforeafter js.

Comment: i got the 404. so how would you suggest i fix it?

Comment: Refer to that js file from your own server or a CDN, whichever possible.

Comment: this is what i have in the head: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.beforeafter.js"></script>

Comment: The question that you posted has `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.beforeafter.js"></script>` and the comment has `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.beforeafter.js"></script>`. Can you please make sure you are referring to it from correct location and its not throwing any 404.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone still reads this thread here:
the linked src's to the js files are wrong. Go to the folder where the js files are and check it. The names in the html file are missing the versionnumbers etc.